# Upgrade/install/remove Firefox 22 went really wrong

Tags: windows-7, firefox, upgrade

I just tried to upgrade my **Firefox** 19 to 22, but after this something went wrong. The last time I tried to upgrade, the same problem appeared and I cannot solve it. So, I downgraded to Firefox 19 and went ahead until today.

Now I upgraded it again (after creating the backups of my profile and all the rest), but the same problem appeared. In short: the window is "messed up", the addons don't work, the tabs of my session are lost and when I recovered a backup of them, Firefox was unable to load the pages.

At this point I decided to remove everything about Firefox and recover it later from my backups. First of all I tried to use the *uninstall/helper.exe* in the Firefox directory, but it doesn't run: I click two times but nothing happens; and the same does the entry in the *Contro Panel/Uninstall a program*. So I decided to get tougher and use Revo Uninstaller Pro (it clear the register and remove all the files and directories around the system left by ad unaccurate uninstaller). But, again, the new installation has the same, identical problems of the upgrade (i tried to remove/install everything tree times).

Here is a screenshot of how actually my Firefox installation looks like:

[image]

There's a way to solve this strange problem?

Comment: It looks like Firefox is starting without any profile at all. What is in the username/appdata/mozilla/firefox/profiles folder?

Comment: @iamwpj There are some directories that seems to be profiles. In *\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\r2oqpg3b.default* and in *C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\r2oqpg3b.default*. But as you can see, also the windows appearance is messed up (the title bar should not be there, the bookmarks bar is just a fake and so on..).

Comment: HTH: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/uninstall-firefox-from-your-computer (Uninstall Firefox from your computer)